# When analyzing a binary compiled from Swift, is it possible to figure out the Swift method name for a function that has no symbol?

Tags: objective-c, swift, reverse-engineering, disassembly

*I'm new to disassembling and reverse engineering binaries, so forgive me if this question is nonsensical or impossible.*

In the past when I've tried reverse engineering macOS binaries, analyzing the ones written in Objective-C yielded a lot of useful information, because generally all of the Objective-C classes and their method names were easily retrievable, making it a lot easier to figure out what any particular method did.

I'm trying to analyze a binary written in Swift (technically a combination of Swift and Objective-C), and most of the functions now have no symbol. There are some Objective-C methods that I can retrieve as usual, and a few functions that have a Swift-style mangled name, but nearly all of the rest have no symbol. I know a lot of those have to be Swift methods.

Is there anyway to figure out what this binary's Swift classes are and their associated methods like I can with Objective-C?

Using a tool like Hopper Disassembler reveals the mangled names of some Swift classes (usually a symbol like `_TtC4Something25SomethingElse`) and I can get a list of its instance variable names and their offsets, but no method names.

*Note: the binary in question is an x64 macOS binary, not an iOS binary.*

Comment: did you try class-dump (on mac) or weak-class-dump (on jailbroken device with Cycript installed)?  I am getting an error on Swift but it works on Objective-C.

Comment: @rustyMagnet Yes, I tried class-dump. That only seems to work with Objective-C methods. However, I haven't tried Cycript before so I'll look into that.

Comment: I tried that. It did not work. This worked https://github.com/Maximus-/class-dump-swift but not in the same league as old Class dump. Today I am going to try Hopper with a De-mangler plug-in..

Answer (score 2):

Usually reverse engineering is the process of extracting meaningful constructs and descriptions from assembly. What you've done so far is usually only the first part of a "normal" reverse engineering task.
This may sometimes be a tedious process, which involves mapping structures and understanding the meaning of functions directly from their assembly code.

There [are](https://github.com/carpedm20/awesome-hacking) [plenty](http://beginners.re/RE4B-EN.pdf) [of](https://www.quora.com/How-can-I-learn-reverse-engineering) reverse engineering tutorials and other sources, and a good understanding of the relevant assembly language is required.
I really recommend [this](http://coolfire.insomnia247.nl/Hacker%20Disassembling%20Uncovered.pdf) book (it's legally available online, original version is `chm` released by author) and this cannot easily be covered in a single SO question.

You might also want to get more specific help in the [reverse engineering](http://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com) SE beta.

I hope I pointed you in the right direction.

Comment: Thanks for the tips. I very well may need to become better at proper reverse engineering in order to do what I want to do, but first I'm specifically asking if there's a process by which I can extract Swift classes and their methods like you can with Objective-C using tools like Hopper or class-dump.

Comment: I didn't explicitly say that but AFAIK there's no way. The reason Hopper or IDA are able to provide you with that information is because symbol information is present in the file. There are other features like RTTI for windows/visual studio but i'm unaware of any similar feature for macos binaries. I hope someone corrects me.

Comment: Downvoted because OP asked a question about the layout of static Swift structures, and this is not an answer to that.

Comment: @Phillip You're free to downvote but the OP did not ask about the Swift structure, but whether it's possible to retrieve function names in some other way. The answer to that question is, unfortunately, no. I go on suggesting what are the best other paths to take.